# Highlighting references included with \nocite

Tags: bibliographies

When working with `\nocite` and `\citep` and creating a bibliography with `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`, how can I highlight references included in the reference list with `\nocite`(but not those with `\citep`) with an asterisk before the reference?

Comment: Not sure how to highlight _not cited_ references in your document but it's fairly easy to build two lists of bibliography: those which are referenced in text and those which are not.